# Return @objc function swift

Tags: swift, closures

Is there any way to return an `@objc` function in swift?

Currently I have this

```
private func getFunction(for index: IndexPath) -> () -> () {
        return {
            print("pressed")
        }
}
```

I am trying to use that as a selector like so

```
UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.getFunction(for: index)))
```

But `#selector` only works with ObjC function, so I would need to do something like this

```
return @objc {
    print("pressed")
}
```

Comment: The value inside `#selector()` needs to be a compile-time reference to a function or property. You can't call a function at runtime and use its result as the argument to `#selector()`.

Comment: And the selector you pass to a gesture recognizer must have either no parameters or one parameter and that one parameter must be the gesture recognizer.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the information. Because of the closure, the function would be called with no parameters. See what I have is return value of the function: `self.getFunction(for: index)` not `self.getFunction(for: index)()`. Anyway, thanks for the answer.